# Do non-rank skill bonuses in linguistics grant bonus langauges?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, languages

Does a character gain bonus languages for other bonuses to the [linguistic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/linguistics) skill such as from class skills, feats, or traits?

> Whenever you put a rank into this skill, you learn to speak and read a new language. Common languages (and their typical speakers) are listed below.

To me this sounds like no, only the ranks (and starting bonus ones from high int) gain you new languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only new ranks grant a new language. Non-rank bonuses only improve the skill for when you use it (such as when deciphering unfamiliar writings or creating/detecting forgeries).